# Trigonometric function differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, derivatives

How can I show that $\sin(x)$ is differentiable? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by differentiable? That the derivative exists?

Comment: no that the integral exists

Comment: A function that has an integral is usually called integrable. What can you assume about $\sin$? If you know that it is continuous, then you can use that any continuous function is integrable over a bounded interval.

Comment: This question was more interesting before the original formula was completely edited away. I'm really puzzled why in the course of a few hours you would stop being concerned about a problem like that and suddenly want to know whether $\sin(x)$ can be differentiated (or integrated).

Comment: Sarcasm? LOL, He probably figured a piece of it out, then the problem changed to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the derivative of $\sin x$, then prove that the derivative is continuous.